# How to atomically insert records with unique ordinal numbers specific to a certain column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concurrency, atomic

I have a database with two tables. The first one holds customers (most columns truncated for brevity):

| CustomerId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Wipers |
| 2 | Wipers Central |
| 3 | Ministores |
| 4 | Minerals |

The second one holds their respective codes, that are used on documents:

| CustomerId | CodePrefix | Ordinal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WIP | 1 |
| 2 | WIP | 2 |
| 3 | MIN | 1 |
| 4 | MIN | 2 |

A customer code consists of a three-letter prefix and an ordinal number. A unique constraint is applied to *CodePrefix* and *Ordinal*.

I struggle to make an SQL statement that inserts new codes to the second table when multiple users try to assign document codes to customers with similar names at the same time.

What I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO CustomerCodes 
(CustomerId, CodePrefix, Ordinal) 
VALUES 
(1, 'WIP',
  (
   SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Ordinal), 0) + 1 
   FROM CustomerCodes 
   WHERE CodePrefix = 'WIP'
  )
)
```

It works most of the time, but for many simultaneous operations I get unique constraint violation.

What should I do to make it work regardless of how many concurrent transactions happens at the same time?

Comment: Add a new column to the first table to track the next ordinal for each client, before the insert, update the column with +1. which will lock the record, and take the previous value as the next ordinal. See this https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/best-code-for-generating-sequence-numbers

Comment: I'd firstly ask, is this necessary? It seems like this customer code is fairly arbitrary, and all you really want is a unique code per customer, so why not just use the customer ID which is already unique, and save yourself some hassle. If for visual reasons you want to include part of the customer name, you could use a computed column [example of this on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gTcmcImy). Either way though, I'd steer clear of generating an additional unique identifier.

Comment: @GarethD it is a business requirement that has to be met. No matter where the client code is stored it must be generated in this way. Another client with the same prefix gets next ordinal number.

Comment: @DouadyRabbit ordinals count for each three-letter prefix not a customer. A single customer can have no more than one code.

Comment: "Business Requirements" should not be above reproach, and if you can achieve the result of having a column that you can combine with code, to make a unique column without the need for maintaining this ordinal field, then you probably should. If you absolutely must do this field you'll need to introduce locking into your query. I am 99% sure that @AaronBertrand has written a great article about this exact requirement, but I cannot find it for love nor money. I will keep looking but hoping that mentioning his name will alert him to it and he can find the article for you.

Comment: I still can't find it - but if memory serves me correctly it was done using an `INSTEAD OF` trigger and inside a transaction to ensure the table was locked for the duration. Something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/y-TZzRAz